# increasing my docker image size inside my virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, docker

I have `ubuntu` installed as a guest in my windows system. At the same time I also have a docker image of `Redhat` stored inside the virtual machine. I can docker run the image inside my `ubuntu` of `200 GB` but now that its size is growing larger and larger, so I need to increase the `Redhat` size of `40 GB` by default up to `100 GB`. How can I do achieve this?